# Is MS Forefront Add-in for Exchange server detecting HTML/Redirector.C incorrectly?

Tags: exchange, anti-virus, microsoft-forefront

Users of a website hosted by our organization occasionally send complaints that our registration confirmation emails are infected with HTML/Redirector.C.  They are always using an MS Exchange Server with the MS Forefront for Exchange AV add-in.  The thing is, I don't think the detection is legitimate.  I think the issue is that the link in the email we send causes a redirect.  I should point out that this is done for a legitimate purpose.  :)  Has anybody run into this before?

Naturally, Microsoft provides absolutely no good information on this one: http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/Threat/Encyclopedia/Entry.aspx?Name=Trojan%3aHTML%2fRedirector.C&ThreatID=-2147358338

I can't find any other explanation of HTML/Redirector.C on the Internet either.  If anyone knows of a real description for this virus that would be greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Please ignore this question.  The detection of the problem by ForeFront WAS legitimate.